# Why a[c] override a[b]?

Tags: javascript, object

I don't understand why the output is 456. I think the b in a[b] is a property of a object, and c is another property of a. They are not related to the var b and c at all. But why a.c override a.b?

```
var a={},
    b={key:'b'},
    c={key:'c'};

a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;

console.log(a[b] === 456); //true
```

Comment: Here, `b` and `c` are properties of `a`, so they are strings. And what's the string representation of an object? "[object Object]"

Comment: This is a duplicate of many previously asked questions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's because property names are strings, but your `b` and `c` are objects. Therefore, they are stringified:

```
b + ''; // "[object Object]"
c + ''; // "[object Object]"
b + '' === c + ''; // true
```

Since they become the same string, the initial value is overridden.

Instead, you may consider using ECMAScript 6 [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which allow you to use any value as keys:

```
var a = new Map(),
    b = {key: 'b'},
    c = {key: 'c'};
a.set(b, 123);
a.set(c, 456);
a.get(b); // 123
```

Answer (score 7):

Your keys are being converted to strings. The string representation is `"[object Object]"`. All you're doing in both cases is this:

```
a["[object Object]"] = 123;
a["[object Object]"] = 456;
```

Proof:

```js
var a={},
    b={key:'b'},
    c={key:'c'};

a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;

console.log(Object.keys(a));
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you don't mind: This seems to be "working" if you instead used a.b=123, a.c=456. Is this only because using [ ] to retrieve a property converts it to string, or am I confused?

Comment: @Mackan No, because then you're literally using `b` and `c` as the property names. You're using `a.b` which is the same as `a['b']` which is the same as `{a: {b: 123}}`. When you write `a.b`, the property name `b` is *not* evaluated as a variable. It has nothing to do with your `b` variable. If you wrote `a.name`, it wouldn't matter if there was a `name` variable in scope, you're still working with the "name" property on the object "a".

Comment: Right, so using `a[b]` tries to evaluate `b` in some sense, but since it's an object it can't and instead it's stingyfied. So `a[b.key]` would actually be `a['b'] == a.b` I assume. Got a a bit caught up in the difference between using periods and []. (edit: I see that you edited while I wrote my response. Thanks, got it!)

Answer (score 0):

Orial is right about that.
JS most troublesome is the data type of variable is not clear at the declaration, though convenient sometimes.

In this case, even you try a[a]==456, it shows true.

a is first initialized as an one-dimensional array, when you try to use it as a map or key-value, you may be expecting an error like this.